# Does adding a new localization (language) in iTunes Connect for an iAP require the IAP to be (re)-approved?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I have an existing app in the AppStore that has in app purchases (IAP) configured and approved in English. If I add a language for localisation (e.g. dutch), does the **IAP** need to be re-submitted for approval?

Answer (score 0):

You've likely already figured this out but for those who come across this looking for an answer.

The IAP itself will not need to be re-approved however the title and description for that new localization will be reviewed by Apple, so you will see a yellow dot next to it until this has been reviewed and will turn green if it is accepted and red if it isn't.